# Is there a way to use google charts table to show different table when searched

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

For example, when I select class 1, it will only show the leaderboard of class 1. If I select class 2 it will only show the leaderboard of class 2. And if I select both classes it will show both leaderboard.

Comment: Hey Syka, welcome to SO! Please show us what you have tried and what you expect as a result. You can find more info about how to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for replying, sorry i don't have the code to show because I am quite new to website coding and i don't know where to start for this. But the result i am trying to achieve is basically creating a leaderboard that will change to another set of data when a button is pressed. Sorry if this is too vague, i really don't have any relevant code to show :(

Comment: @Syka this can easily be accomplished using [dashboard controls](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#overview)...

Comment: @WhiteHat That solved my problem. Thank you!